# What is the use of default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

One of the main motto of cpp is to avoid uninitialized variables. Then what is the use of default constructor that compiler provides as it doesn't initialize variables.

Comment: I think you mean the implicitly generated default constructor in particular, not just any default constructor.

Comment: The whole point is that it provides a place where you *can* initialize your object.

Comment: "One of the main motto of cpp is to avoid uninitialized variables." - really?  Where'd you get that from?

Answer (score 2):

The implicitly generated default constructor calls the default constructors of all members and base classes. They may or may not be implicitly generated (meaning, some member, or member's member, etc, may have a non-implicitly generated default constructor, one that actually does something).

Comment: Thanks dave , but for a simple class which don't have member classes or base classe, is there any use of compiler defined default ctor.

Comment: My point is if compiler wont have provided default constructor and have given error , we would be warned that we missed constructor and would have a place to INITIALIZE variables.

Comment: @user2967369 It's not inherently wrong to not initialize a variable. It's wrong to use a primitive before it has been initialized or assigned. For example, you might write... `int x; cin >> x;` - there is no reason to initialize `x` here. C++ (almost) always offers the lowest common denominator of what you could want. I'm not saying that your proposition is bad, it was probably a matter of convenience that we have _any_ implicitly generated constructors/operators.

Comment: @user2967369 I think you should change your Q title to "Why are there implicitly generated default constructors?"... there are probably a number of legacy reasons - importantly, compatibility with C.

Answer (score 1):

There are some circumstances in which a default constructor is required. For example

```
MyClass arrayOfObjects[10];
```

Here the default constructor is called even if then you are going to assign new values to objects in the array. Or a derived class ctor which doesn't explicitly call a parent constructor. Or even a simple declaration of a variable:

```
MyClass x; // calls default constructor
...
x = ..;
```